# Strange behaviour - Recyclerview onItemClick isn't working properly if Root Layout is there

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, onitemclicklistener, android-radiobutton

**Problem:**
I'm having a recyclerview, in adapter of that recyclerview, I have solely **RadioButton** without any parent layout like **LinearLayout** or **RelativeLayout**. This time onItemClick is working fine. If I will add parent layout like **LinearLayout** or **RelativeLayout**, it doesn't invoke onItemClick.

My code is like below.

**FilterJobsCategoryAdapter.java**

```
    public class FilterJobsCategoryAdapter
        extends
        RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>
        implements
        APIServiceConstants {

    private int lastSelectedPosition = -1;

    private Context mContext;
    private List<String> mItem;
    private OnItemClickListener mOnItemClickListener;

    public FilterJobsCategoryAdapter(Context context, List<String> item) {
        this.mItem = item;
        this.mContext = context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View layoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.rv_item_filter_jobs_category, parent, false);
        return new RecyclerViewHolders(layoutView);
    }

    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        final RecyclerViewHolders viewHolder = (RecyclerViewHolders) holder;
        viewHolder.rb_filter_category.setText(mItem.get(position));

        if (lastSelectedPosition == -1 && position == 0) {

            viewHolder.rb_filter_category.setChecked(true);
            viewHolder.rb_filter_category.setClickable(false);
            viewHolder.rb_filter_category.setTextColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryBlue));
            viewHolder.rb_filter_category.setBackgroundColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryBlue));
            viewHolder.rb_filter_category.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

        } else {

            if (lastSelectedPosition == position) {
                viewHolder.rb_filter_category.setChecked(true);
                viewHolder.rb_filter_category.setClickable(false);
                viewHolder.rb_filter_category.setTextColor(mContext.getResources()
                        .getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryBlue));
                viewHolder.rb_filter_category.setBackgroundColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryBlue));
                viewHolder.rb_filter_category.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

            } else {
                viewHolder.rb_filter_category.setChecked(false);
                viewHolder.rb_filter_category.setClickable(true);
                viewHolder.rb_filter_category.setTextColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.blackTextColor));
                viewHolder.rb_filter_category.setBackgroundColor(mContext.getResources()
                        .getColor(R.color.lightGreyBg80));
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mItem.size() > 0 ? mItem.size() : 0;
    }

    class RecyclerViewHolders extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        @BindView(R.id.rb_filter_category)
        RadioButton rb_filter_category;

        RecyclerViewHolders(View view) {
            super(view);

            ButterKnife.bind(this, view);

            view.setOnClickListener(v -> {
                lastSelectedPosition = getAdapterPosition();
                mOnItemClickListener.onClick(lastSelectedPosition);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            });
        }
    }

    public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener) {
        this.mOnItemClickListener = onItemClickListener;
    }

    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        void onClick(int position);
    }
}
```

**rv_item_filter_jobs_category.xml** (onItemClick doesn't work for this code)

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/rb_filter_category"
        style="@style/FilterCategoryRadioButtonStyle" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/dp1"
        android:background="@color/lightGreyBg80" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**rv_item_filter_jobs_category.xml** (onItemClick works for this code)

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RadioButton xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/rb_filter_category"
    style="@style/FilterCategoryRadioButtonStyle" />
```

**style.xml**

```
<style name="FilterCategoryRadioButtonStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.CompoundButton">
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/roboto_medium</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">start|center_vertical</item>
    <item name="android:maxLines">1</item>
    <item name="android:includeFontPadding">false</item>
    <item name="android:hint">@string/str_view_by</item>
    <item name="android:padding">@dimen/dp10</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/sp12</item>
    <item name="android:ellipsize">end</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/blackTextColor</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:button">@null</item>
</style>
```

I don't understand what is going on here.. it's strange! Any guidance would definitely be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting `clickable` to false on the `RadioButton`. Since you're actually setting the `onClickListener` on the root view it is possible that the `RadioButton` intercepts the touch event so it's never called on the root.

Comment: For the sake of testing I converted **RadioButton** to **TextView**. I tried to setting clickable false in XML file but facing same issue.

Comment: I recreated your solution in my project and it's working correctly with `android:clickable="false"` on RadioButton and `android:clickable="true" android:focusable="true"` on the root view. Maybe try that?

Comment: Let me give another shot to your solution. Give me some minutes. I will let you know@ErnestZamelczyk

Comment: Can you give me your code? I have tried the same thing you said, but is isn't working here@ErnestZamelczyk

Comment: It's literally just a simple adapter with onClickListener on root. Maybe this line from your `onBindViewHolder` is interfering?: `viewHolder.rb_filter_category.setClickable(true);`

Comment: I'm happy to hear that.

Answer (score 0):

What is exactly the problem: with a parent layout, the radiobutton is displayed as selected but the method

```
view.setOnClickListener(v -> {
                lastSelectedPosition = getAdapterPosition();
                mOnItemClickListener.onClick(lastSelectedPosition);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            });
```

is not properly called?

So for me, it seems normal, since view is now the parent layout, and when you click item, you select the radio button firstly. Normally, if you put padding the parent layout, and click on the border of item, it must work.

Just set onClickListener to your radiobutton should solve the problem

```
rb_filter_category.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        lastSelectedPosition = getAdapterPosition();
        mOnItemClickListener.onClick(lastSelectedPosition);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    });
```

And avoid snake case for variable name in java.

Edit: for less call, make the viewholder implement OnClickListener, and add

```
lastSelectedPosition = getAdapterPosition();
                mOnItemClickListener.onClick(lastSelectedPosition);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
```

in the onclick method

Comment: Let me check this solution. Thanks for the other advices@FlorentBreton

Comment: Your solution worked for me. But I'm wondering what's the exact difference between `view.setOnClickListener` and `rb_filter_category.setOnClickListener`

Comment: Don't write like that. If the viewholder implement onClickListener, it aks you to add an onClick method where you write the good code, and in the constructor, add view.setOnClickListener(this) and rb_filter_category.setOnClickListener(this)

Comment: I understood your point, but I want to know the difference between `view.setOnClickListener` and rb_filter_category.setOnClickListener`? Actually @ErnestZamelczyk solutions worked for me, without doing major changes. Thanks for your help